# Проблема с переопределением "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Переопределил `SerializerMethodField` django-rest-framework

```html
class CustomSerializersMethodField(serializers.SerializerMethodField):
 def __init__(self, title, method_name=None, **kwargs):
   self.title = title
   super(serializers.SerializerMethodField, self).__init__(method_name=None, **kwargs)
```

и получил ошибку

```html
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method_name'
```

Связано ли это с замечанием в [доках](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)?

> The serializer method referred to by the method_name argument should
>   accept a single argument (in addition to self)

Что я сделал неправильно? И какой объект использовать для создания своих кастомных полей с необходимыми аргументами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня сейчас не установлено Django и я не могу проверить свою догадку, но подозреваю, что вам всё-таки нужно вызывать super не от SerializerMethodField, а от того класса, который вы создаёте(т.е. CustomSerializersMethodField).

По крайней мере, обычно при переопределении init делают именно так.